# Tizen .NET Stream Player

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, media-player, http-live-streaming, tizen

I'm trying to find a solution to play 'HLS/TS' content from URI.

I'm coding on VS (xamarin forms/cross platform) but can't found a way or Renderer for my Tizen project.

at the moment I have this function ( But it's not compatible with updated version of xamarin.forms) and it can't play HLS/TS stream (just video content 'like mp4/mkv'):

```
public async Task PrepareAsync()
    {
        State = PlayerState.Preparing;

        var display = new Multimedia.Display(Forms.Context.MainWindow);
        _player.Display = display;

        await _player.PrepareAsync();

        State = PlayerState.Prepared;
    }
```

***Thank you***

Answer (score 0):

**It may be possible that ExoPlayer can help you.**

ExoPlayer is an open source library that exposes the lower-level Android audio APIs. ExoPlayer supports high-performance features like DASH and HLS streaming that are not available in MediaPlayer. You can customize the ExoPlayer code, making it easy to add new components. ExoPlayer can only be used with Android version 4.1 and higher.

To make use of ExoPlayer, add the following code to your `MainActivity` (Xamarin):

```
((MediaManagerImplementation)CrossMediaManager.Current).MediaSessionManager = new MediaSessionManager(Application.Context, typeof(ExoPlayerAudioService));
var exoPlayer = new ExoPlayerAudioImplementation(((MediaManagerImplementation)CrossMediaManager.Current).MediaSessionManager);
CrossMediaManager.Current.AudioPlayer = exoPlayer;
```

and also have a visit here:

[Run iptv & ts urls in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444253/run-iptv-ts-urls-in-android)

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

https://blog.xamarin.com/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but ExoPlayer is just available for Android project :-(,
Not for Tizen.TV. I Can't install this nuget package to my project

Comment: its a problem, but if you have time you can grasp logic from exoplayer and create your own.